# Is there any options for customizing search results template?

Tags: orgchart

I need to customize default template of search results of BALKANGraph OrgChartJS. Where do i find the solution for customizing template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BALKANGraph developer here

you can customize the search result with CSS

also you can implement your own search result ui by defining mySearchUI class:

```
var mySearchUI = function () {
};

mySearchUI.prototype.init = function (obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
};

mySearchUI.prototype.hide = function () {

};

mySearchUI.prototype.show = function (callback) {

};

mySearchUI.prototype.addSearchControl = function () {

};

mySearchUI.prototype.find = function (value) {

};
```

And

```
var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
    nodeBinding: {
        field_0: "name"
    },
    nodes: [
        { id: 1, name: "Amber McKenzie" },
        { id: 2, pid: 1, name: "Ava Field" },
        { id: 3, pid: 1, name: "Peter Stevens" }
    ],
    searchUI: new mySearchUI()
});
```